# Why use axis=-1 in Keras metrics function?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

keras version:2.0.8

In some Keras metric functions and loss functions, use axis=-1 as parameter.

For example：

```
def binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.equal(y_true, K.round(y_pred)), axis=-1)
```

In my case:

shape of y_true:(4,256,256,2)

shape of y_pred:(4,256,256,2)

So, binary_accuracy(y_true, y_pred) should return a tensor with shape=(4,256,256) instead of a scalar tensor.

But when use binary_accuracy as metric function:

```
model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, metrics=[binary_accuracy])
```

The log still prints binary_accuracy as scalar,which confused me a lot.

Does keras do some special on the return of binary_accuracy function?

> Epoch 11/300
>
> 0s - loss: 0.4158 - binary_accuracy: 0.9308 - val_loss: 0.4671 -
>   val_binary_accuracy: 0.7767

Comment: Why do you think binary accuracy should return a tensor instead of a scalar?

Comment: Because the functions are implemented in a way that returns tensors. The step that transoforms the tensors in a scalar is hidden somewhere else.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro According to binary_accuracy function, it should return a tensor (not scalar tensor )with shape=(4,256,256).I test it, it's true.

Comment: @DanielMöller Sure but the log will always print a scalar, that is what confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for, inside [training_utils.py](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training_utils.py#L447):

```py
def weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask=None):
    """Wrapper function.
    # Arguments
        y_true: `y_true` argument of `fn`.
        y_pred: `y_pred` argument of `fn`.
        weights: Weights tensor.
        mask: Mask tensor.
    # Returns
        Scalar tensor.
    """
    # score_array has ndim >= 2
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
    if mask is not None:
        # Cast the mask to floatX to avoid float64 upcasting in Theano
        mask = K.cast(mask, K.floatx())
        # mask should have the same shape as score_array
        score_array *= mask
        #  the loss per batch should be proportional
        #  to the number of unmasked samples.
        score_array /= K.mean(mask) + K.epsilon()

    # apply sample weighting
    if weights is not None:
        # reduce score_array to same ndim as weight array
        ndim = K.ndim(score_array)
        weight_ndim = K.ndim(weights)
        score_array = K.mean(score_array,
                             axis=list(range(weight_ndim, ndim)))
        score_array *= weights
        score_array /= K.mean(K.cast(K.not_equal(weights, 0), K.floatx()))
    return K.mean(score_array)
return weighted
```

The metric function is called by `score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)` (it's a nested function and `fn` is defined in the outer function). This array is averaged in the last line `return K.mean(score_array)`. That's why you're seeing scalar metrics instead of tensors. The lines in between are just to introduce masks and weights if necessary.

Comment: This reply explains why it's ok that the mean is only taken wrt the last axis, but I'm still not sure why the design is like this. It sounds like the mean is taken later anyway, so why take the mean with axis=-1 in the loss function? Wouldn't it be more efficient to take no mean in the loss function definition?