# What is the meaning of axis=-1 in keras.argmax?

Tags: keras, axis, argmax

I am a beginner in Keras and need help to understand `keras.argmax(a, axis=-1)` and `keras.max(a, axis=-1)`. What is the meaning of `axis=-1` when `a.shape = (19, 19, 5, 80)`? And also what will be the output of `keras.argmax(a, axis=-1)` and `keras.max(a, axis=-1)`?

Comment: Somebody's following deeplearning.ai's convolutional neural networks course :-)

Comment: Adding to the excellent answer by Daniel Möller, if your data has a shape `(19,19,5,80)` then `keras.max(a, axis=-1)` would return a matrix of shape `(19,19,5)` where each value of the output matrix would be the maximum of the 80 elements (the maximum of the values specified within the last index)

Answer (score 196):

This means that the index that will be returned by argmax will be taken from the last axis.

Your data has some shape `(20,19,5,80)`, I changed the first dimension just to make it clearer. This means:

- Axis 0 = 20 elements
- Axis 1 = 19 elements
- Axis 2 = 5 elements
- Axis 3 = 80 elements

Now, negative numbers work exactly like in python lists, in numpy arrays, etc. Negative numbers represent the inverse order:

- Axis -1 = 80 elements
- Axis -2 = 5 elements
- Axis -3 = 19 elements
- Axis -4 = 20 elements

When you pass the `axis` parameter to the `argmax` function, the indices returned will be based on this axis. Your results will lose this specific axes, but keep the others.

See what shape `argmax` will return for each index:

- `K.argmax(a,axis= 0 or -4)` returns `(19,5,80)` with values from `0 to 19`
- `K.argmax(a,axis= 1 or -3)` returns `(20,5,80)` with values from `0 to 18`
- `K.argmax(a,axis= 2 or -2)` returns `(20,19,80)` with values from `0 to 4`
- `K.argmax(a,axis= 3 or -1)` returns `(20,19,5)` with values from `0 to 79`

Comment: Thank you! 
I was working with a different data structure, and it turns out for me it was important to use the Keras axis indexing as something like K.sum(three_dimensional_array, axis=[0,1]).

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298110/why-use-axis-1-in-keras-metrics-function/46312367#46312367