# Discrepancy between keras CosineSimilarity metrics and cosine similarity computed between target and predicted vector

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrent-neural-network, cosine-similarity

I have trained a sequential model in keras, with sparse vectors as inputs (`padded_inputs_multil` for training and `padded_inputs_tr` for testing) and dense vectors as output (`target_multil_array` for training and `target_tr_r_array` for testing):

```
model_mul=keras.models.Sequential()
model_mul.add(keras.layers.LSTM(units=172, batch_input_shape=(None, 29, 22), dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, return_sequences=False))
model_mul.add(Dense(300, activation='tanh')) 

model_mul.compile(loss='cosine_similarity', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)])
model_mul.summary()

history_mul=model_mul.fit(padded_inputs_multil, target_multil_array, epochs=1, validation_data=(padded_inputs_tr, target_tr_r_array))
```

And I get a cosine similarity of .4607, in the following output:

```
Train on 794870 samples, validate on 199108 samples
Epoch 1/1
794870/794870 [==============================] - 2694s 3ms/step - loss: -0.4678 - cosine_similarity: 0.4522 - 
val_loss: -0.4152 - val_cosine_similarity: 0.4607
```

However, when I evaluate the model, I get a lower value of cosine similarity:

```
results_mul = model_mul.evaluate(padded_inputs_tr, target_tr_r_array)
print(results_mul)
```

```
[-0.4152175833690755, 0.44675499200820923]
```

Then, the worse problem: if I compute the predicted vectors and compare them with the target vectors, I get a mean cosine similarity that is much, much lower (slightly higher than .40). I can't understand why, since on the tensorflow documentation I find that CosineSimilarity keeps the average cosine similarity between predictions and labels.

```
prediction_mul = model_mul.predict(padded_inputs_tr)
column_names = ['prediction_multil', 'target_multil', 'cos_pred_target']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
df['prediction_multil'] = [vec for vec in prediction_mul]
df['target_multil'] = [vec for vec in target_tr_r_array]

def cos_sim(a, b):
    dot_product = np.dot(a, b)
    norm_a = np.linalg.norm(a)
    norm_b = np.linalg.norm(b)
    return dot_product / (norm_a * norm_b)

cos = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # print(cos_sim(row['prediction_multil'], row['target_multil']))
    cos.append(cos_sim(row['prediction_multil'], row['target_multil']))
df['cos_pred_target'] = [value for value in cos]
statistics.mean(df['cos_pred_target'])
```

Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Hi there! In Keras, "cosine_similarity" [loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/cosine_similarity) should converge to -1? On the other hand, "CosineSimilarity"  [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/CosineSimilarity) should go towards 1, right?

Comment: @isydmr Yes, but what surprised me was not the discrepancy between the loss and the metrics, but by the discrepancy between the value of the metric when fitting and evaluating the model, and when computing the mean of the cosine similarity between target and predicted vector

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cosine_similarity documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/cosine_similarity), the default `axis` value is `axis=-1`

and as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435526/what-is-the-meaning-of-axis-1-in-keras-argmax) `axis=-1` means it will take the last shape axis. So for your case `axis=-1` is equivalent to `axis=2`.

So the result is that the **loss** in computing in one axis, and the **metrics** on another:

```
model_mul.compile(loss='cosine_similarity', optimizer='adam', metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity(axis=1)])
```