# what is the meaning of axis=-1 in tf.keras.layers.Normalization?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, normalization

I'm trying to learn deep learning using keras and tensorflow and I came across a code explaining linear regression at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/regression wherein they have created a normalization layer using normalizer = tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1). Someone please explain the meaning of axis =-1 . I tried looking at the API documentation but I couldnt understand the explanation from there?I know that axis=0 represent rows and axis=1 columns, right?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47435526/what-is-the-meaning-of-axis-1-in-keras-argmax

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/preprocessing_layers/numerical/normalization/) this layer is:

> A preprocessing layer which normalizes continuous **features**.

Then, under the description of `axis`:

> Defaults to -1, where the last axis of the input is assumed to be a **feature dimension** and is normalized per index.

From these two statements, we can see that `-1` in this context just means the last axis. This is actually fairly common in Python, for example you can index for the last element in a list using `-1`.