# Keras custom loss function outputs negative values, dont understand why?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, calculation, loss-function

Dear StackOverflow Community,
I have the following loss function in keras:

```
return K.mean((y_true+K.epsilon()) * K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

When I try to train my network (y normalized to 0 - 1) with it,
the loss appears to get to an negative value, which I just can't understand. 
I calculated the same thing with numpy, and everything worked fine and as intended.

I would be really delighted If someone knows the cause for this weird negative solutions, so thank you for your help.

Comment: why do you use `axis=-1`?

Comment: Because it automatically use the last axis then, which, in my case is the forth one.

Comment: then output of `mean` will be an array and loss must be just a number. And also strange that tensors `y_true` and `y_pred` have ranks 4 and that they are not just 1-rank vectors.

Comment: Not really.... if you check for all the standard keras loss function, they only apply the mean on the last axis as well. This allows you to further use their functions with balance coefficients and other stuff.

Comment: @DanielMöller you are right. Have found this answer for ["why axis=-1 in loses"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46312367/6689249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y_true` is really normalized to 0-1 that only possible cause that I see is `K.epsilon()`. As [this page](https://keras.io/backend/) suggest epsilon can be changed by user and this can cause a problem.

Try to hardcode epsilon value or just throw it away.

Comment: I checked epsilon on the data center right now, it appears to be 1^-7, so it isn't the problem

Comment: I accepted your answer because it led me to double checking the original values, so It works now. thanks for your help