# Keras/Tensorflow: Channel Order First and loss functions axis -1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I see that from [Keras source](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/5a7a789ee9766b6a594bd4be8b9edb34e71d6500/keras/losses.py), the loss function for, for example `mae` is defined as

```
def mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.abs(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

and this would produce a `NHW` tensor which has `mae` loss for each pixel, assuming channels are at the end.

and from this question [Why use axis=-1 in Keras metrics function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46298110/3125070), I get to understand that K.mean is called before printing things it to log.

I use `channel_first` ordering for my images i.e., `NCHW` and there is no `channel_order` checking conditional statement there.

**Will this affect the way losses are backpropagated (or is there ANYthing else I need to worry)?** Or should I manually create loss functions from there with `axis=1`? Or is it okay if don't include the axis at all, making the loss function return a single scalar rather than a tensor? What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you using a CNN for image classification? By the time the loss is computed, the output of your convolutional layers has probably has been flattened anyway so using `channel_first` should not make any difference.

Comment: yes, cnns with NCHW order

Comment: For reference on axis=-1 in loss function, be sure to also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46298110/why-use-axis-1-in-keras-metrics-function/46312367#46312367